# Delete message command for moderators

Tags: node.js, macos, bots, discord, discord.js

I am working on a Discord bot and has been reading the API lately. I want to add a command for my bot which will clear a text channel entirely, and will only allow people with a permission to manage messages.

This is my code so far:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.content == "^clear") {
        try {
            if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
                messages = message.channel.fetchMessages();
                message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            message.channel.send("ERROR: ERROR CLEARING CHANNEL.");
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

});
```

I get an error which looks like this:

```
TypeError: The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number.
at TextChannel.bulkDelete (/Users/person/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:379:11)
at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/person/bpt/bot.js:29:33)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:188:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/Users/person/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/Users/person/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:102:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/Users/person/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:325:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/Users/person/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:288:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/person/bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/EventTarget.js:103:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, you can't bulk delete messages older than 14 days so if you're trying to clear a channel with messages over 14 days old, it won't work with bulk delete, you'd have to delete them one at a time (while/for loop), I'm assuming you know this as its on the docs. Secondly, `message.channel.fetchMessages()` returns a `Promise` meaning it isn't  ready at the time you're accessing it. You'll have to either use `async/await` or just `.then`. Example:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.content == "^clear") {
        if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
            message.channel.fetchMessages()
               .then(function(list){
                    message.channel.bulkDelete(list);
                }, function(err){message.channel.send("ERROR: ERROR CLEARING CHANNEL.")})                        
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: message.channel.fetchMessages() become message.channel.message.fetch()

Answer (score 1):

this is for message. and not for msg.

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "clear")){
    const amount = message.content.split(" ")[1];
    if(!amount)
    {
        message.reply(`<amount>`);
        return;
    }
     if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
     {
        message.channel.send('You have no permissions to do that');
        return;
     }
    message.channel.bulkDelete(amount)
    //.then(messages => message.channel.send(`${messages.size} Messages deleted`))
.then(messages => message.channel.send(`Messages deleted by ${message.author.username}`))
.catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple code, and if u want in the message.channel.bulkDelete(type in ur custom number) coz this will only delete 5 messages. But keep in mind that maximum is 100.

```
/////////////////Clear Chat//////////////////////////////////

client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content === "/clearchat 5") {
    message.channel.bulkDelete(5)
    .then(messages => console.log(`Bulk deleted ${messages.size} messages`))
    .catch(console.error);
 message.channel.send("Chat cleared");
  }
})
///Make ur own trigger and edit the response/////////////
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the permission that the question asks for. This is also hard coded to delete only 5.

Comment: Yeah but u can change it where it says messag.channel.bulkDelete(add ur own number)